# The mathematics of dollar cost averaging

Tags: dollar-cost-averaging

Does anyone have a reference to a detailed mathematical analysis of the process of dollar cost averaging and whether it is really beneficial?

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/129/does-dollar-cost-averaging-really-work) isn't detailed enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is beneficial when compared to buying a fixed number of shares. [Here's an introductory analysis](https://sciencehouse.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/dollar-cost-averaging/). In summary, cost averaging yields the harmonic mean of the entry prices. The resulting cost basis is biased towards the lower outliers. The beneficial effects are more noticeable as volatility increases.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: +1 An introductory article that uses calculus? Great for "detailed mathematical analysis", bad for my brain...

Comment: Nice article, but note, it compares equal dollar purchases vs equal number of shares. Not lump sum.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer but it still provides a good framework to think about how DCA works. Thanks!